# How do I Rotate, Translate, and Scale rectangle from a keyframe using popmotion pure?

Tags: javascript, animation, keyframe, popmotion

**How do I make the last keyframe rotate my rectangle to a 35deg angle using popmotion pure?**

[image]
https://codepen.io/matthewharwood/pen/XWmRPaK?editors=1111

HTML:

```
<div class="flex h-screen w-screen justify-center items-center">
  <div class="portal-b">
    <h1 class="left"></h1>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="trigger fixed z-10 left-0 top-0">
  B replace A
</button>
```

CSS:

```
.portal-b {
  background: blue;
  width: 1px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

JS

```
const { easing, keyframes, styler } = window.popmotion;
const trigger = document.querySelector('.trigger');
const [_, portalB] = [document.querySelector('.portal-a'), document.querySelector('.portal-b')];
trigger.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const portalS = styler(portalB);
  keyframes({
  values: [
    { translateX: 0, scaleX: 0, rotateZ: 0, transformOrigin: 'left center' },
    { translateX: 200, scaleX: 400, rotateZ: 0, transformOrigin: 'left center' },
    { translateX: 200, scaleX: 400,  rotateZ: 90,  transformOrigin: 'left center' },
  ],
  duration: 3000,
  easings: easing.easeInOut,
}).start(portalS.set)
})
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For this kind of problem I recommend stepping through the values in plain CSS in your browser. I found that the following CSS rule provided the final state you wanted

```css
.portal-b {
  background: blue;
  width: 1px;
  height: 100px;
  transform: translateX(200px) rotate(-35deg) scaleX(400);
}
```

Then all you need is for your keyframes to step their way there, stating explicitly the values they expect like so

```
  values: [
    { transform: "translateX(0px) rotate(0deg) scaleX(1)" },
    { transform: "translateX(200px) rotate(0deg) scaleX(400)" },
    { transform: "translateX(200px) rotate(-35deg) scaleX(400)"},
  ],
```

Here's your pen with my changes:
https://codepen.io/kcerb/pen/wvKyWLv?editors=1111

Comment: @Matthew Harwood added a copy of your codepen with the values above pasted in. I believe this gives the behavior you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution using Popmotion Pure, using the built-in transform options rather than a transform string:
https://jsfiddle.net/rqjahwLt/

You're correct that the trouble is math-based. You need to set the dimensions of your rectangle in your CSS to be what you want at the end of the animation.

The trouble is Popmotion Pure will apply `rotateZ`, before it applies `scaleX`.

### The solution:

The CSS uses width to set the dimensions desired at the end of the animation, and transform to set the dimensions desired at the beginning. If you set `width: 1px`, then your `rotateZ` is applied before `scaleX`, which leaves you with a rhombus (i.e. skewed rectangle) instead of a rotated rectangle as desired.

```css
.portal-b {
  background: blue; 
  width: 300px; /* set the width to what you want at the end */
  height: 100px;
  transform: scaleX(0.001); /* transform the width to what you want at the start */
}
```

The Javascript then only has to un-set our `transform: scaleX(0.001)` from above. The second keyframe will animate the rectangle from being width = 0.3px to width = 300px. Then the final keyframe rotates this to -35deg around the Z axis.

```js
  values: [
  { translateX: 0, scaleX: 0.001, rotateZ: 0, transformOrigin: 'left center' },
    { translateX: 200, scaleX: 1, rotateZ: 0, transformOrigin: 'left center' },
    { translateX: 200, rotateZ: -35,  transformOrigin: 'center' },
  ],
```